# JQuery count up with a timeout or endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timer which counts up to a figure based on a set of results from the database. however, when the data isnt present the timer will just keep going with no timeout or end point.

Is there a way I can either not show the timer if the value does not exist or show 0/40 see my code below:

```
$(function() {
    function count($this) {
        var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
        $this.html(++current);
        if (current !== $this.data('count')) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                count($this)
            }, 50);
        }
    }        

    $(".fiveStarScore").each(function() {
        $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
        $(this).html('0');
        count($(this));
    });
});
```

This is the div that is targeted and will stop at the desired value.

```
<div>
    <span class="fiveStarScore"><?php echo $total_five_stars;?></span>/40
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by checking if the text value of the element on load is `0` (or is any non numerical value) and not calling `count()` if so:

```js
$(function() {
  function count($el) {
    var current = parseInt($el.text(), 10);
    $el.html(++current);

    if (current !== $el.data('count')) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        count($el)
      }, 50);
    }
  }
  
  $(".fiveStarScore").each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var total = parseInt($el.text(), 10) || 0;
    $el.data('count', total).text('0');
    
    if (total == 0)
       return;
    
    count($el);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span class="fiveStarScore">0</span>/40
</div>

<div>
  <span class="fiveStarScore">25</span>/40
</div>
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what im looking to do - thank you, it makes sense now